# Go GORM two table requests

Tags: go, go-gorm

So I am new to GORM and I have this task where I have two tables `accounts` and `users`

I get the `user.Id` and I need to get the `accountId` from the `user` table afterwards I need to only get the account that has the same `Id` as `user.AccountId`

```
type User struct{
    Id int
    AccountId int
}

type Account struct{
    Id int
    Balance int
}
```

It looks like this should be a pretty simple call to do it in a single request, but I can't find a simple implementation for this logic. Can anyone help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this, and below are a couple of them. I'm assuming that the `db` variable is of type `*gorm.DB`. Also, I'm the code below is suited for MySQL (minor changes are needed for PostgreSQL).

**Load just the Account data with joins**

```
var account Account
err := db.Joins("JOIN users ON users.account_id = account.id").Where("users.id = ?", user.Id).First(&account).Error
```

**Load the User object with the Account data**

Here there are a few changes to the `User` struct, but the underlying code is simpler. Also, it loads the entire `User` object, with the related `Account` object.

```
type User struct{
    Id int
    AccountId int
    Account Account
}

var fullUser User
err := db.Preload("Account").First(&fullUser, user.Id).Error
```